# How to reference Context object in provided class methods?

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

We are using *graphql-java* and with `com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaParser` (from *graphql-java-tools*) we are creating executable schema - and it works just fine. Now we need to add user information and propagate it to our graphql method logic. The obvious approach is to use "context" object.

So, in `mutations.graphql` file there is:

```
type Mutations
  createGroup(input: CreateGroupInput): IdRequest
  ...
```

On the other hand, there is a Java class with the corresponding method:

```
IdRequest createGroup(CreateGroupInput input) {
  ...
}
```

Then, when calling `graphql.GraphQL.execute(myQuery, contextObject)` how to read this `contextObject` into Java method above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing I was looking for is `DataFetchingEnvironment` (see [Fetching data](https://graphql-java.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data_fetching.html?highlight=DataFetchingEnvironment)).

The "contextObject" can then be retrieved in Java class by adding `DataFetchingEnvironment` as a last argument, like:

```
IdRequest createGroup(CreateGroupInput input, DataFetchingEnvironment environment) {
  Object contextObject = environment.getContext();
  ...
}
```